# I need to upload a lot of files

Tags: php, laravel, uploadcare

My files are stored in laravel progect storage\app\file.jpg , file1.jpg etc
I need to upload for example 3 files.
I use:

```
foreach ($doc['imageIds'] as $image_id) {
    $imageBinary = $this->client->getImageBinary($details->inspection_id, $image_id);
    $name_file = $doc_type.'-'.$profile->model_type.'-'.$profile->model_id.'-'.$image_id.'.jpg';
    $path_file = storage_path('app\\'.$name_file);
    Storage::put($name_file, $imageBinary);
    $api = new Uploadcare\Api($uc_public_key, $uc_secret_key);
    $file = $api->uploader->fromPath($path_file);
    $store = $file->store();
    Storage::delete($name_file);     
    dd($store);
}
```

next I use uuid for Group upload
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTt7D.jpg)
and get this 
`https://ucarecdn.com/8f5e00a3-a58d-474e-9d07-184af6aff2fe~3/`
How can I do group file upload via library? 
"uploadcare/uploadcare-php": "^2.2",

Comment: yes, I corrected the tex. I'm looking for a way to conveniently upload files of my backend php laravel

Comment: in the end I want to get this https://ucarecdn.com/8f5e00a3-a58d-474e-9d07-184af6aff2fe~3/  from my local files

Comment: Which part of the upload logic do you need help with?

Comment: you need to use `Uploader->createGroup()` method: https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-php/blob/master/src/Uploadcare/Uploader.php#L239-L260

Comment: yes, its work
Uploader->createGroup() work